# Given a string, find two identical subsequences with consecutive indexes C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I need to construct an algorithm (not necessarily effective) that given a string finds and prints two identical subsequences (by print I mean color for example). What more, the union of the sets of indexes of these two subsequences has to be a set of consecutive natural numbers (a full segment of integers).

In mathematics, the thing what I am looking for is called "tight twins", if it helps anything. (E.g., see the [paper (PDF) here](https://www.google.com/search?q=avoiding+tight+twins+in+sequences&btnl).)

Let me give a few examples:

1) consider string 231213231

It has two subsequences I am looking for in the form of "123". To see it better look at this image:

[image: 231213231]

The first subsequence is marked with underlines and the second with overlines. As you can see they have all the properties I need.

2) consider string 12341234

[image: 12341234]

3) consider string 12132344.

Now it gets more complicated:

[image]

4) consider string: 13412342

It is also not that easy:

[image]

I think that these examples explain well enough what I meant.

I've been thinking a long time about an algorithm that could do that but without success.

For coloring, I wanted to use this piece of code:

```
 using namespace std;
HANDLE  hConsole;
        hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, k);
```

where k is color.

Any help, even hints, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If exptime algorithms are ok, the task is easy.

Comment: Every kind of algorithm is okay, since I won't be considering strings longer than 30.

Comment: I vote for reopening because the question seems interesting.

Comment: I don't believe it was justified to put this question on hold as too broad. The OP has asked for an algorithm to satisfy a well defined requirement. Stack Overflow would gain if people were allowed to suggest algorithms to satisfy that requirement, and to compare the complexities of the various algorithms (the fact that the OP is satisfied with an exptime algorithm does not affect this). As it happens, I believe that it can be satisfied in polynomial time by simulating a set of NFAs, where each NFA has a state that gives the number of characters allocated to each sequence.

Comment: Does the substring comprising the two subsequences have to be maximal-length?  If not, this means (for example) that we can stop as soon as we see any pair of adjacent equal characters (possibly this can be generalised).

Comment: @j_random_hacker: No, I want to stop as soon as I find tight twins. For example if I have a string: 1231123123, I could stop when finding "11".

Comment: Good to know.  That means that we can limit ourselves to searching for minimal-size substrings -- that is, substrings having the property and that do not contain any proper substring that also has the property.  Not sure if this can be turned into an algorithmic improvement yet, but perhaps it could...

Comment: What is the minimum length of the substring here? A substring "1234" will always form substrings "1","2","3","4","12","13"... etc. What are the constraints of substring matching?

Comment: @VedangMehta: As I stated above - minimal length of a substring is 1 and we don't have to consider substrings of a substring because it's the same thing as considering all substrings of input string.

Comment: @Mateusz so in the example "231213231", "2" is also a valid substring as it appears more than once, right? Then, what is the need to find bigger substrings? We can just pick those characters that appear more than once.

Comment: @VedangMehta: I think you have misunderstood the problem. I'll see if I can put it another way: Think of the length-n string as a mathematical function f mapping an integer i in the range 1 ... n to a character.  We are looking for 2 sets of integers, A and B, such that the following conditions all hold: (1) A and B are disjoint; (2) the union of A and B is some integer *interval* (i, j) with 1 <= i <= j <= n (i.e. with no "gaps"); (3) if we list the integers in A in increasing order and apply f to each, the string of (j-i+1) characters we get equals the string we get if we do the same with B.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I didn't get the "no gaps" part before. Nice explanation, anyway :)

Comment: @VedangMehta: You're welcome :)

Comment: I had thought that it might be that no minimal solution could have a subsequence that begins and ends with the same character, but I found a counterexample: 1231412341 = 123.41.... + ...1..2341, and no proper substring also has a solution.

Comment: It is at least possible to show that in any minimal-length solution, every character from subsequence A precedes its matching character in subsequence B.  This can be used to speed up an algorithm; I'll post an answer later.

Comment: WARNING: My algorithm is probably wrong -- please see the comments on my answer.  :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple recursion that tests for tight twins. When there's a duplicate, it splits the decision tree in case the duplicate is still part of the first twin. You'd have to run it on each substring of even length. Other optimizations for longer substrings could include hashing tests for char counts, as well as matching the non-duplicate portions of the candidate twins (characters that only appear twice in the whole substring).

Explanation of the function:

First, a hash is created with each character as key and the indexes it appears in as values. Then we traverse the hash: if a character count is odd, the function returns false; and indexes of characters with a count greater than 2 are added to a list of duplicates - characters half of which belong in one twin but we don't know which.

The basic rule of the recursion is to only increase `i` when a match for it is found later in the string, while maintaining a record of chosen matches (`js`) that `i` must skip without looking for a match. It works because if we find `n/2` matches, in order, by the time `j` reaches the end, that's basically just another way of saying the string is composed of tight twins.

JavaScript code:

```js
function isTightTwins(s){
  var n = s.length,
      char_idxs = {};

  for (var i=0; i<n; i++){
    if (char_idxs[s[i]] == undefined){
      char_idxs[s[i]] = [i];
    } else {
      char_idxs[s[i]].push(i);
    }
  }

  var duplicates = new Set();

  for (var i in char_idxs){

    // character with odd count
    if (char_idxs[i].length & 1){
      return false;
    }

    if (char_idxs[i].length > 2){
      for (let j of char_idxs[i]){
        duplicates.add(j);
      }      
    }
  }

  function f(i,j,js){

    // base case positive
    if (js.size == n/2 && j == n){
      return true;
    }

    // base case negative
    if (j > n || (n - j < n/2 - js.size)){
      return false;
    }

    // i is not less than j
    if (i >= j) {
      return f(i,j + 1,js);
    }

    // this i is in the list of js
    if (js.has(i)){
      return f(i + 1,j,js);

    // yet to find twin, no match
    } else if (s[i] != s[j]){
      return f(i,j + 1,js);

    } else { 

      // maybe it's a twin and maybe it's a duplicate
      if (duplicates.has(j)) {
        var _js = new Set(js);
        _js.add(j);
        return f(i,j + 1,js) | f(i + 1,j + 1,_js);          

      // it's a twin
      } else {
        js.add(j);
        return f(i + 1,j + 1,js);
      }
    }
  }

  return f(0,1,new Set());
}

console.log(isTightTwins("1213213515")); //  true
console.log(isTightTwins("11222332")); // false
```

Comment: This looks on the whole good, but it gives a false positive for `console.log(isTightTwins("11222332"));`.  The problem seems to be that after the first 2 characters match, f(1, 2, {1}) is called, which then notices that i=1 is already in js and then calls f(2, 2, {1}) -- from this point on, we are matching some characters with themselves.  I think you need to force the invariant that i < j somehow.

Comment: I don't know JS, but I was able to add some basic debugging output to your code in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xzwsp8vz/.

Comment: I'm having some trouble trying to figure out exactly what the function call f(i, j, js) returns -- could you maybe describe it in words?  Thanks.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thanks for noticing the bug. I added a call to increase `j` if it's not greater than `i`, which seems to work with your example. Please let me know if you notice another. I was going to think about your interpretation of `f()` but see you've removed the comment. I'll try and formulate a worded interpretation as you suggest. That would be a good exercise, too.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't quite describe it right so I deleted it, hoping to minimise confusion!  I think your fix makes the algorithm correct :)  I've decided that mine is also correct in the case where there are no duplicates (as you noticed), but mine takes quadratic time in this case while yours is linear-time.  Yours also has the advantage that you can easily change it to return `js` in the cases where it currently returns `true`, i.e. you get the actual solution "for free" :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thanks for your comments. I added an explanation in words; does that make sense? The function seems to be linear (per substring of the original larger string) were it not for duplicates, since for each duplicate greater than two, the decision tree splits, adding more traversals.

Comment: Nice description.  Thinking about it some more, I think our solutions have the same time (O(n) per length-n substring, for O(n^3) total) in the case where there are no duplicates, but yours has the important advantage of *being correct* even when there are duplicates ;-)

Comment: @j_random_hacker Please let me know if I'm thinking about it correctly -- assuming no duplicates, since LCS will cover prefixes and each call is quadratic, for a 6-character-string you would need: `6^2 (start-idx 0; len 6,4,2) + 4^2 (start-idx 1; len 4,2) + 4^2 (start-idx 2; len 4,2) + 2^2 (start-idx 3; len 2) + 2^2 (start-idx 4; len 2) = 76` iterations. Mine would need `5*2 + 3*4 + 6 = 28`.

Comment: Counting iterations might be good for estimating constant factors, but I get the time complexities a different way: Assuming no duplicates, your algorithm has at most 1 recursive call per invocation of f(), so the call tree is a path.  Every recursive call increases at least 1 of i or j, and you maintain j > i and stop recursing once j >= n, so the deepest path from the root can be in the worst case at most 2n nodes.  A call tree that has depth at most 2n nodes and is a path has at most 2n nodes in total, i.e. it's linear-time.

Comment: @j_random_hacker yea, I think I get that; I was thinking about the searches we would need through the total string in which we are looking for substrings that are composed of tight twins.

Comment: As for my algorithm, it's basically the standard LCS DP algorithm, so I can get an answer for *every prefix* of the length-n string in O(n^2) time, so I need to run it O(n) times, for a O(n^3) overall.  Your algorithm needs to be run on all O(n^2) substrings so it's also O(n^3) overall.  But maybe it could be brought down to O(n^2) overall...   One way to do this, would be to somehow get it to check whether *any prefix of* the input string is TT, in the same time complexity as it's currently using.

Comment: @j_random_hacker that's exactly right, because of it's cumulative "memory," LCS covers all *prefixes* (not subsequences) for the string on which it is run - if you want to know if there's a tight twin substring starting on index 3 of your total string, you need to run another LCS, starting on index 3 - that's what I tried to show in my above computation. Am I not getting LCS?

Comment: I don't understand which part your disagreeing with...  My claims are (1) that my algorithm takes O(n^2) time to check n prefixes, and thus needs to be run O(n) times for a total of O(n^3); and (2) that your algorithm takes O(n) time to check 1 substring, and thus needs to be run O(n^2) times for a total of O(n^3).

Comment: @j_random_hacker lol, let me think about it (...why do the iterations in my above calculation seem significantly different?)

Comment: If you mean "Why do the iteration counts for your algorithm seem very different to mine?", that's easily explained by a constant factor.  If the ratio kept growing even as the strings got very long, that would be stronger evidence that they have different time complexities.

Comment: @j_random_hacker yes, I see it, they are of similar complexity. I'd like to learn more about recognizing a constant factor.

Comment: Well, the best you can do empirically is run both algorithms on increasingly large inputs, and see what happens as n gets large.  (When n is small, the definitions of time complexity allow the results to "bounce around", but above some certain threshold, the ratio should converge to a constant.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker right, and that's also when real-life system and language implementations also come into play and can sometimes surprise.

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING: Commenter גלעד ברקן points out that this algorithm gives the wrong answer of 6 (higher than should be possible!) for the string 1213213515.  [My implementation](http://ideone.com/I4CiJy) gets the same wrong answer, so there seems to be a serious problem with this algorithm.  I'll try to figure out what the problem is, but in the meantime DO NOT TRUST THIS ALGORITHM!**

I've thought of a solution that will take **O(n^3) time and O(n^2) space**, which should be usable on strings of up to length 1000 or so.  It's based on a tweak to the usual notion of longest common subsequences (LCS).  For simplicity I'll describe how to find a minimal-length substring with the "tight twin" property that starts at position 1 in the input string, which I assume has length 2n; just run this algorithm 2n times, each time starting at the next position in the input string.

### "Self-avoiding" common subsequences

If the length-2n input string S has the "tight twin" (TT) property, then it has a common subsequence with itself (or equivalently, two copies of S have a common subsequence) that:

- is of length n, and
- obeys the additional constraint that no character position in the first copy of S is ever matched with the same character position in the second copy.

In fact we can safely tighten the latter constraint to **no character position in the first copy of S is ever matched to an equal or lower character position in the second copy**, due to the fact that we will be looking for TT substrings in increasing order of length, and (as the bottom section shows) in any *minimal-length* TT substring, it's always possible to assign characters to the two subsequences A and B so that for any matched pair (i, j) of positions in the substring with i < j, the character at position i is assigned to A.  Let's call such a common subsequence a *self-avoiding* common subsequence (SACS).

The key thing that makes efficient computation possible is that no SACS of a length-2n string can have more than n characters (since clearly you can't cram more than 2 sets of n characters into a length-2n string), so if such a length-n SACS exists then it must be of maximum possible length.  **So to determine whether S is TT or not, it suffices to look for a maximum-length SACS between S and itself, and check whether this in fact has length n.**

### Computation by dynamic programming

Let's define f(i, j) to be the length of the longest self-avoiding common subsequence of the length-i prefix of S with the length-j prefix of S.  To actually compute f(i, j), we can use a small modification of the usual LCS dynamic programming formula:

```
f(0, _) = 0
f(_, 0) = 0
f(i>0, j>0) = max(f(i-1, j), f(i, j-1), m(i, j))
m(i, j) = (if S[i] == S[j] && i < j then 1 else 0) + f(i-1, j-1)
```

As you can see, the only difference is the additional condition `&& i < j`.  As with the usual LCS DP, computing it takes O(n^2) time, since the 2 arguments each range between 0 and n, and the computation required outside of recursive steps is O(1).  (Actually we need only compute the "upper triangle" of this DP matrix, since every cell (i, j) below the diagonal will be dominated by the corresponding cell (j, i) above it -- though that doesn't alter the asymptotic complexity.)

To determine whether the length-2j prefix of the string is TT, we need the maximum value of f(i, 2j) over all 0 <= i <= 2n -- that is, the largest value in column 2j of the DP matrix.  This maximum can be computed in O(1) time per DP cell by recording the maximum value seen so far and updating as necessary as each DP cell in the column is calculated.  Proceeding in increasing order of j from j=1 to j=2n lets us fill out the DP matrix one column at a time, always treating shorter prefixes of S before longer ones, so that when processing column 2j we can safely assume that no shorter prefix is TT (since if there had been, we would have found it earlier and already terminated).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but could you tell me how to get from yours algorithm (which, if I am right, only determines whether string has tight twins or not) to an algorithm that actually prints tight twins?

I know I might sound silly, but I am only a beginner at programming.

Comment: Utilizing your function as provided (string index is starting at 0, I assume?), I get different results for this, `"1213213515" (5)`, and this, `"1213243545" (4)`. With string indexing starting at 1, the function yields 6 and 5 respectively. Notice that the first string contains one duplicate 1 instead of the 4 in each twin. Can we assume that a result longer than half the string is always valid, just implies duplicates?

Comment: @Mateusz and j_random_hacker, here are some strings for which the function in this answer seems to return false positive. In one of them, some chatacters appear an odd number of times; in the other, the character counts are even: 
`"1213213525"` and `"1213215351"`.

Comment: @גלעדברקן: Thanks for your comments.  I've now implemented the DP in C++ here: http://ideone.com/I4CiJy and I get the same answers as you do in your first comment (I've assumed 1-based strings) -- a very strong indication that there's something fundamentally wrong with my algorithm :(  I'll put up a warning and investigate further...

Comment: I added a simple recursion, but I'm not sure how much can be done if the twins each contain duplicates. I think that the LCS ought to work when there are no duplicates but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1):

Let the string length be N.

There are two approaches.

Approach 1. This approach is always exponential-time.

For each possible subsequence of length 1..N/2, list all occurences of this subsequence. For each occurence, list positions of all characters.

For example, for 123123 it should be:

```
(1, ((1), (4)))
(2, ((2), (5)))
(3, ((3), (6)))
(12, ((1,2), (4,5)))
(13, ((1,3), (4,6)))
(23, ((2,3), (5,6)))
(123, ((1,2,3),(4,5,6)))
(231, ((2,3,4)))
(312, ((3,4,5)))
```

The latter two are not necessary, as their appear only once.

- One way to do it is to start with subsequences of length 1 (i.e. characters), then proceed to subsequences of length 2, etc.  At each step, drop all subsequences which appear only once, as you don't need them.
- Another way to do it is to check all 2**N binary strings of length N. Whenever a binary string has not more than N/2 "1" digits, add it to the table. At the end drop all subsequences which appear only once.

Now you have a list of subsequences which appear more than 1 time.  For each subsequence, check all the pairs, and check whether such a pair forms a tight twin.

Approach 2. Seek for tight twins more directly. For each N*(N-1)/2 substrings, check whether the substring is even length, and each character appears in it even number of times, and then, being its length L, check whether it contains two tight twins of the length L/2.  There are 2**L ways to divide it, the simplest you can do is to check all of them.  There are more interesting ways to seek for t.t., though.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to approach this as a dynamic programming/pattern matching problem. We deal with characters one at a time, left to right, and we maintain a herd of Non-Deterministic Finite Automata / NDFA, which correspond to partial matches. We start off with a single null match, and with each character we extend each NDFA in every possible way, with each NDFA possibly giving rise to many children, and then de-duplicate the result - so we need to minimise the state held in the NDFA to put a bound on the size of the herd.

I think a NDFA needs to remember the following:

1) That it skipped a stretch of k characters before the match region.

2) A suffix which is a p-character string, representing characters not yet matched which will need to be matched by overlines.

I think that you can always assume that the p-character string needs to be matched with overlines because you can always swap overlines and underlines in an answer if you swap throughout the answer.

When you see a new character you can extend NDFAs in the following ways:

a) An NDFA with nothing except skips can add a skip.

b) An NDFA can always add the new character to its suffix, which may be null

c) An NDFA with a p character string whose first character matches the new character can turn into an NDFA with a p-1 character string which consists of the last p-1 characters of the old suffix. If the string is now of zero length then you have found a match, and you can work out what it was if you keep links back from each NDFA to its parent.

I thought I could use a neater encoding which would guarantee only a polynomial herd size, but I couldn't make that work, and I can't prove polynomial behaviour here, but I notice that some cases of degenerate behaviour are handled reasonably, because they lead to multiple ways to get to the same suffix.